# Can I initialize jQuery Datepicker into a div on load?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use jQuery Datepicker, but not in the way it's being used most times. Instead of activating on click above the field, I'd like to load it into a div on every page load.

Is there way I can do that?

Comment: trigger a click action on load?

Comment: If u provide your code, I can help you where to change

Comment: Sorry, the duplicate is poor, but your answer is there.